# Display image according to the String from list

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I have a list of strings and a set of images.

```
import 'dart:math';

var list= [
  "one",
  "two",
  "three",
];

final _random = new Random();
var stringslist = list[_random.nextInt(list.length)];
```

And the set of images are as follows. "one-image.jpg", "two-image.jpg", "three-image.jpg"

A random string will get selected from the list, and will be set in `var stringslist`. How can I get the image for the selected string.

The code for both in the screen are as follows,

```
final planetCard = new Container(
  child: new Text('''   Did You Know?
$stringsfacts''',
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: TextStyle(
    letterSpacing: 1.2,
    fontSize: 24.0,
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
  ),
  height: 250.0,
  width: 350.0,
  margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 60.0,top: 70.0),
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    color: new Color(0xFF333366),
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
    boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
        new BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black12,
          blurRadius: 25.0,
          offset: new Offset(5.0, 10.0),
        ),

      ],
  ),
);
final planetThumbnail = new Container(
  margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
      vertical: 10.0
  ),
  alignment: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
  child: new Image(
     image: new AssetImage("assets/images/moon.png"), //This should change accroding to the selected String
     height: 125.0,
     width: 125.0,
   ),
);
```

[image: This is the Screen]

The string and image should match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list= [
  "one",
  "two",
  "three",
];

final _random = new Random();
var stringsList = list[_random.nextInt(list.length)];

// on your widget
Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/" + _filterImage(stringsList))),

// method filter image
String _filterImage(String stringsList) {
  switch (stringsList) {
     
     case list[0]:
       return "one-image.jpg";
       break;
     case list[1]:
       return "two-image.jpg";
       break;
     case list[2]:
       return "three-image.jpg";
       break;
     default:
       return "placeholder.jpg";
       break;
  }
}
```

**if you have 2 list, list of string and list of images**

```
var listOfString= [
  "one",
  "two",
  "three",
];

// list of images
var listImages= [
  "one-image.jpg",
  "two-image.jpg",
  "three-image.jpg",
];

var stringsList = listOfString[_random.nextInt(list.length)];
var selectedImage = listImages[listOfString.indexWhere((val) => val == stringsList)];

// on your widget
Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/$selectedImage")),
```

**if you have only 1 list of images**

```
// list of images
var listImages= [
  "one-image.jpg",
  "two-image.jpg",
  "three-image.jpg",
];

var selectedImage = listImages[_random.nextInt(list.length)];

 // on your widget
Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/$selectedImage")),
```

thats maybe simple your code

Comment: Is there a way I can set the case like ```list[0]``` . Without typing the entire string, Because some strings are large.

Comment: i've updated the code above with list[index]

Answer (score 1):

```
child: new Image(
    image: stringslist = "one" ? AssetImage("assets/images/one-image.png") : stringslist = "two" ? AssetImage("assets/images/two-image.png") : stringslist = "three" ? AssetImage("assets/images/three-image.png") : AssetImage("assets/images/moon.png")  ,
```

If you don't have a lot of images this would do.

Comment: I have about 100 or more in the list so this might not work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable and assign `int index = _random.nextInt(list.length)`
and use the same index variable to get the values also from the list of your image string

Answer (score 0):

You can use ${} to interpolate the value of Dart expressions within strings. The curly braces can be omitted when evaluating identifiers.

```
String imageName;

setState(() {
  imageName = list[Random().nextInt(list.length)]
})

Image(
 image: new AssetImage("assets/images/$imageName"),
 height: 125.0,
 width: 125.0,
),
```